# Horizontally scrolling a single image

Tags: android, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I have an image which is of dimension `3000 x 1500` pixel. I want it to fit the screen vertically and I should be able to scroll it horizontally.

**Project in GITHUB**: https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo
https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo/archive/master.zip

**Image link:** https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo/raw/master/app/src/main/res/drawable/peace.jpg

Following is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPink"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorYellow"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/peace" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> In Android studio preview of the layout file I can find it working as I expected.

[image: Android studio preview]

> In the actual device, One Plus 3T with android 8.0.0, the image is showing as below

[image: Actual Device]

- compileSdkVersion 27
- minSdkVersion 15
- targetSdkVersion 27

`dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}`

**EDIT**

So after adding background colors to my layouts, below is what I got. Looks like the Image view is not expanding to its parent view.

[image: Actual Device1]

Comment: Did you try an Image with 3000 x 3000 In the real device..? I think it's because of that

Comment: Can you try using match_parent in horizontal scroll view height?

Comment: Try the image which I asked you before... Make the Image height more than 1500

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cropView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/peace"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</HorizontalScrollView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, Now the image is filling up the screen vertically, but it is being cropped now and there is some spaces after the image at the horizontal end

Comment: give your image i will check.

Comment: Here is my project in github https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo

Comment: Image: https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo/raw/master/app/src/main/res/drawable/peace.jpg

Comment: try my edited code and important thing is move your image into mipmap folder from drawable

Comment: no need to use glide only transfer your image into mipmap folder. i will run on my htc with 2 gb ram it's work fine bro.

Comment: The image source load by the server URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the device. OnePlus uses a customised OS which causes problems in such views.

Try the device with Android One OS or default Android OS.

It works fine with my device Moto X Play. Android 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your linear layout with a relative layout and add this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/peace" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Nope, still the same with `RelativeLayout` as well.

Comment: @Zeeshan I update my answer if it did not work try to remove 'ConstraintLayout'

Comment: See my updated question. Looks like the Image view is not expanding to its parent view.

Comment: @Zeeshan try to remove ConstraintLayout

Comment: Removing ConstraintLayout didn't worked as well. I have added Project in GITHUB: https://github.com/rameezalam/imagescrolldemo

Comment: try to add 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
to the main xml parent

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:fillViewport="true"` to HorizontalScrollView and make its `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Use `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/peace" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```